# Dynamically import self-generated python files within a pyinstaller generated .exe

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

`Pyinstaller 3.4`
`Python 3.7 (Windows 7)`

I have a use-case where my main python script, `foo.py`, generates a `traylist.py` file that I want to import stuff from. 
`foo.py` occasionally has to update this `traylist.py` file. Therefore, there is a need for `foo.py` to be able to import that `traylist.py` again in a function. I accomplish this using a reload module function like this:

`import traylist
importlib.reload(traylist)
menu_def = traylist.menu_def`

I have also tried the following code with the same results (works within interpreter but fails when run as .exe)

`import traylist
del sys.modules['traylist']
import traylist
menu_def = traylist.menu_def`

All this works when running `foo.py` within the normal interpreter (`python foo.py`). However, when I create a `--onefile` .exe using pyinstaller, the values in the traylist module never refresh. I've checked the paths using sys._MEIPASS and can see the new file generated in the MEIxxx folder. I just can't get the .exe to reload that module correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that while pyinstaller lets you bundle other types of files and  access them through the `sys._MEIPASS` path, that does not hold true for `import module` statements. It has a separate way that it handles those kinds of files and can't be changed easily resulting in stale copies of the same original module getting reloaded.

The solution was to load a module by providing its full path. Their are various methods to accomplish this but the one that worked for me was the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6284270/3439096) answer. First I had to do a `pip install import_file`, then:

    `from import_file import import_file
    traylist = import_file(traylist_path)`